# Foreach loop item groups must add up to 3

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am coding a PHP foreach loop.  I am using the following code to ensure that only 3 items are grouped into a .slide div container.

```
<?php 
$count = 0;
foreach ($listing as $item):?>
<div class='slide>

  <div class='item'>Item</div>

<?php if ($count++ % 3 == 1 ): ?>
</div>
<div class="slide">
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

I need to always have 3 items per group.  What is the best way to add items from the start of the array to fill up the remaining items?

**EDIT**:

An example of the markup I need is:

```
<div class='slide'>
  <div class='item'>Item 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Item 2</div>
  <div class='item'>Item 3</div>
</div>
<div class='slide'>
  <div class='item'>Item 4</div>
  <div class='item'>Item 1</div>
  <div class='item'>Item 2</div>
</div>
```

So if there is not 3 items per .slide  the array starts again to fill it up.

Comment: what you want exactly? as <div class=slide><div class=item/><div class=item/><div class=item/></div> like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to append 1 or 2 items (if required) to the `$listing` variable before the loop.

```
if (count($listing)%3!=0) {
    //Append 1 or 2 items from start of array if needed
    $listing = array_merge($listing, array_slice($listing, 0, 3-count($listing)%3));
}
```

The `array_slice` call returns an array containing items from `0` to `3 - (size of array) mod 3` (either 1 or 2). The `array_merge` function then adds these 1 or 2 items to the original `$listing` array. The complete code (with some other minor improvements/fixes) is below:

```
<?php 
    $count = 0;
    $listing = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    if (count($listing)%3!=0) {
        //Append 1 or 2 items from start of array if needed
        $listing = array_merge($listing, array_slice($listing, 0, 3-count($listing)%3));
    }
    ?><div class='slide'> <?php
    foreach ($listing as $item):
        if (($count>0) and ($count%3==0)):
            ?></div><div class="slide"><?php
        endif; 
        ?><div class='item'>Item <?=$item?></div><?php
        $count++;
    endforeach;
    ?></div><?php
?>
```

Depending on your data, you might need to add special checks for the case where the original `$listing` has 0 or 1 items. Also, probably a good idea not to modify the original array and instead use a copy to append items to and use in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 3):

Needed to do this recently with Bootstrap, wrap a row around every 3 columns, and couldn't find a good working answer, so here's the solution I came up with. Hope it helps.

```
<?php
$count = 0;
foreach ($listing as $item) {
  if ($count % 3 == 0) {
    echo "<div class='slide'>";
  }
  $count++;
?>
<div class='item'>Item</div>
<?php
  if ($count % 3 == 0) {
    echo "</div>";
  }
}
?>
```

These links will help explain the operators so you can understand what's going on:

[PHP Arithmetic Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (% = Modulus)

[Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) (++ = Post-increment)

Comment: Modulus and Increment operators FTW!